# Druid services going down without any specific error

Tags: druid

I see this error message before services go down.

**2020-07-26T18:48:25,466 INFO [Thread-131] org.apache.druid.java.util.common.lifecycle.Lifecycle - Lifecycle [module] running shutdown hook
2020-07-26T18:48:25,468 INFO [Thread-131] org.apache.druid.java.util.common.lifecycle.Lifecycle - Stopping lifecycle [module] stage [ANNOUNCEMENTS]
2020-07-26T18:48:25,469 INFO [Thread-131] org.apache.druid.curator.announcement.Announcer - Unannouncing**strong text****

This happens for all the services. The services go down after 2-3 hours. I have set the log level to debug mode and still I do not see specific errors.

My services are configured to run like this

Zookeeper cluster runs on a 3 node cluster. These nodes are different from druid cluster nodes.

Druid 0.18.1 cluster runs on 6 node cluster

2 for data services - i3.4x large

2 for master - m5.2xlarge

2 for query - m5.2xlarge

Overlord runs within coordinator.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you check if there are any errors in syslog? Maybe the service is shut down because your system is out of memory? We have seen similar cases where certain processes where killed because of insufficient memory.

Comment: I did check . System is not out of memory. There is some daemon service on Ec2 which was killing the druid services on ec2 instances. As soon as I started the services inside docker container with the same config, it successfully ran. Never figured out why it happened when I ran services natively on Ec2 instances.